# Debian apt-get update says ''Unable to find expected entry"

Tags: apt

My 32 bit debian (version: Debian GNU/Linux 8) installation is suddenly giving me the following messages when I run `apt-get update`.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The funny part is that I did not add any additional sources. Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list file. It's default.

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.7.1 _Jessie_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20170116-10:07]/ jessie main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.7.1 _Jessie_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20170116-10:07]/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

Now I don't know how to solve this. Can this file somehow gets corrupted? Can I revert it back? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: It's popssibly the repository mirror you have selected, `ftp.nl.debian.org`, has opted to no longer carry the 32-bit package builds.  Check with the mirror maintainer and, in the meantime, you can look for another repository mirror which has not done so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the `jessie-updates` from your sources.list

[stable-updates](https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates)

> For Debian 8 "Jessie", jessie-updates no longer exists as this suite no longer receives updates since 2018-05-17.
>
> The next time you run `apt-get update`, the system will become aware of the packages in the (old)stable-updates section and will consider them when looking for packages to upgrade.